# How to change order of pages in InnoSetup?

Tags: inno-setup, pascal, swap

I would like to swap the SelectDir page with the Components page in my setup.

I found a solution where the content of the other page is assigned to the current page.

```
Procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
Begin
  Case CurPageID of
  wpSelectDir:
    begin
      WizardForm.SelectDirPage.Notebook.ActivePage:= WizardForm.SelectComponentsPage;
      WizardForm.PageNameLabel.Caption:= SetupMessage(msgWizardSelectComponents)
      WizardForm.Hint:= WizardForm.PageDescriptionLabel.Caption;
      WizardForm.PageDescriptionLabel.Caption:= SetupMessage(msgSelectComponentsDesc)
    end;
  wpSelectComponents:
    begin
      WizardForm.SelectComponentsPage.Notebook.ActivePage:= WizardForm.SelectDirPage;
      WizardForm.DiskSpaceLabel.Caption:= WzardForm.ComponentsDiskSpaceLabel.Caption;
      WizardForm.PageNameLabel.Caption:= SetupMessage(msgWizardSelectDir)
      WizardForm.PageDescriptionLabel.Caption:= WizardForm.Hint
    end;
  end;
End;
```

The problem using this method is that only the content but not the actual page is changed. Message boxes and error messages are not affected. I wrote many lines of code to work around these problems but I encounter more and more problems...

Is there a better solution? I hope you can help me!

Edit: After experimenting a bit I came up with this:

```
procedure RedesignWizard;
var
  Page: TWizardPage;
begin
  Page := CreateCustomPage(wpWelcome, 'bla', 'bla');
  WizardForm.ComponentsList.Parent := Page.Surface;
  //Here  I am changing the layout of the pages...
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  RedesignWizard;
end;

procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  if (CurPageID = Page.ID) then
  begin
  //perform your actions specific to the Custom page here.
  end;
end;
```

This way the components list appears before the SelctDirPage and I do not have any more problems with those message boxes.

Comment: In short, don't do that. There are checks binded to the *Next* button click and those are driven by the page ID constants whose you can't override. Imagine what happens when you'll have components page *visible* to user who click the *Next* button and (with a certain circumstances) a default directory in the directory edit box will already exist. Yes, the *"The folder: c:\something already exists. Would you like to install to that folder anyway ?"* message dialog pops up from the components page, what is nonsense.

Comment: I'm aware of this and thus wrote some checks to show a message using a TLabel on the page and disable the Next button in the solution above. I really need to swap these pages and if there is a simpler solution, I would like to know. I can handle the remaining stuff on my own.

Comment: If we misunderstood each other.... The problems you mention occur when using the method shown above. I disabled all message boxes and tried to work around the problems with the message boxes on the wrong pages but I encouter more and more problems. This is why I would like to use another method since I really need to swap those pages. Is it possible to create a custom page and assign the values of the SelectComponentsPage to it? Or even some other way? Otherwise I will have to get rid of each problem.

Comment: There's the only one way to not get into trouble - simulate the *Next* and *Back* button clicks, what is IMHO impossible.

Comment: Couldn't I create a custom page with a TNewCheckListBox and assign it to the WizardForm.ComponentsList and a TNewStaticText assigned to WizardForm.ComponentsDiskSpaceLabel? Or something with the Notebook?

Comment: No, the properties are read-only.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is absolutely no way to safely swap the order of any of the builtin pages.  (And usually, the only time people ask is when they are trying to replicate the flow of a different installation system.  Relax and let it go; Inno works differently, embrace it instead of fighting it.)

Having said that, it is possible to give the appearance of swapping the pages, by recreating one or the other of them as a custom page.  However by doing this you will forfeit all of the built-in functionality associated with that page -- eg. if you replace the components page then you cannot use the [Components] section or parameters, and if you replace the directory page then you cannot use {app} (not even in those places that use it implicitly, such as the UninstallFilesDir).

If you're willing to put in a lot of time and effort (especially testing), it can be done.  But everything is worse off as a result -- so normally you're better off not doing so.

Comment: Has this capability been added in more recent builds of INNO?
I only want to have the Select Location page show if certain components are being installed. Otherwise I don't need to display that page. But I can't tell if it needs to be displayed until the components have been selected.

Comment: @Toby Nope.  My answer still applies.

Answer (score 0):

To add to what Miral said:

```
[Setup]
DisableDirPage=yes // disable the built-in page

[Code]
var
  ApacheDirPage: TInputDirWizardPage;
  ApacheDir: AnsiString;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  { Create the custom wizard pages }
    ApacheDirPage := 
       CreateInputDirPage( wpSelectComponents,  // display AFTER select Type/Components page
                           'Select Apache Directory', 
                           'Select the Apache x.x Directory' + #13#10 + '(the one that contains the BIN folder)',
                           'Select the Apache directory, then click Next.',
                           False, '' );
   ApacheDirPage.Add( '');           
   ApacheDirPage.Values[0] := csApacheLocation;
end;
```